# create pdf with title + image in php

Tags: php, pdf

I have following array which contain titles and their respective images.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title1 : Introduction
            [image] => http://path/to/file.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => Title2 : Description
            [image] => http://path/to/file.jpg
       )
     .
     .
     .
     //and so on

)
```

I want to create PDF of it like : 
Array[0] content on page1: 
Title on top (align : center) and below it
Image (align : center, height:400, width:400)

Same like array[1] content on page 2 on so on...

I am doing like this but not getting any success. Check my code below:

```
<?php    
include_once ('class.ezpdf.php');

$feeddata = unserialize(urldecode($_GET['feed']));

$pdf = & new Cezpdf('LETTER');

$image = imagecreatefrompng("background.png");
$pdf->addImage($image, 0, 0, 611);

$pdf->selectFont("fonts/Helvetica.afm");
$pdf->setColor(0 / 255, 0 / 255, 0 / 255);

$pdf->setLineStyle(0.5);
$pdf->line(80, 615, 540, 615);
$pdf->setStrokeColor(0, 0, 0);

$pdf->setColor(0 / 255, 0 / 255, 0 / 255);
$pdf->addText(30, 16, 8, "<b>Created " . date("m/d/Y"));

foreach($feeddata as $data){
    $pdf->addText(80, 620, 10, $data['title']);
    $pdf->addImage($data['image'], 0, 0, 611);
}   

$pdf->ezStream();
?>
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do it....thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I solved it myself :

I just used this :

```
foreach ($feeddata as $data) {
    $pdf->ezText($data['title'], 15);
    $pdf->ezImage($data['image'], 50, 300, none, center);
}
```

Now it is displaying the title and image in my pdf file.....quite easy :-)